# ReferenceError: 'Camera' is undefined at addImage () using ionic and ngCordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

```
app.controller('InsideCtrl', function($scope, AuthService, API_ENDPOINT, $http, $state, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaFile) {

$scope.addImage = function() {
  // 2
    var options = { 
      destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, // Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
      allowEdit : false,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  };
```

this is the appjs file where i'm getting the error. I'm using ionic serve -l -c commmand to run ionic server. I've tried to uninstall android and ios platform plus cordova plugins but nothing helped me out.

Comment: Never used Ionic or Cordova, but...surely it should be `$cordovaCamera` instead?

Comment: $cordovaCamera being used  in controller's scope

Comment: Have you took a look on your android/src/org/apache/cordova/camera directory. When this directory does not exist, then this plugin is not installed  even after the steps you've done. Have you really done all steps that were done [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-camera-is-not-defined-when-using-cordovacamera/12994/3)

Comment: @AsadArshad clearly the Camera plugin hasnt been initialized by the time you are trying to access it.